# Confusing SARIMAX Parameter Estimates from Simulated ARMA Data

Tags: arima, statsmodels

I've been working on simulating ARMA (Autoregressive Moving Average) time series data in Python and fitting ARIMA models using the `SARIMAX` class from the `statsmodels` package. However, I've encountered some puzzling results in the parameter estimates, more specifically when including an MA component in my data generating process I get $\hat{c} = 0.002, \hat{\theta_{1}} = 0.261, \hat{\theta_2} = -0.069$ while in fact $c = 0.002, \theta_{1} = 0.3, \theta_2 = -0.1$ (even though I have 80,000 observations).

I think it's fair to assume `SARIMAX` is implemented correctly but at the same time I don't see the error in my simulation. I was hoping maybe someone can spot my error.

Below is my implementation for generating ARMA data and fitting the models:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

def generate_arma_data(intercept, ar_coefficients, ma_coefficients, std_eps, n_periods):

    # For later use: ARMA(p, q)
    p = len(ar_coefficients)
    q = len(ma_coefficients)

    # Generate normal errors centered around 0 with the specified standard error
    eps = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=std_eps, size=n_periods+max(p, q))

    # Initialize
    simulated_data = [0] * max(p, q)

    # Iteratively generate the series
    for t in range(max(p, q), len(eps)):
        # For each AR coefficient we multiply it with the lagged data and sum to get the AR contribution
        ar_component = sum(ar_coefficients[j] * simulated_data[t-j-1] for j in range(p))
        # For each MA coefficient we multiply it with the lagged error and sum to get the MA contribution
        ma_component = sum(ma_coefficients[j] * eps[t-j-1] for j in range(q))
        # Finally add the intercept or constant and add the error of the current timestep
        datapoint = intercept + ar_component + ma_component + eps[t]
        simulated_data.append(datapoint)

    return simulated_data[-n_periods::]

# Initialize
intercept = 0.002 # Constant in the ARMA specification
std_eps = 0.001 # Standard deviation of the errors
n_periods = 80000 # Number of observations in our sample
ma_coefs = [0.3, -0.1] # Coefficients for the MA terms

# Generate the data
data_ma_2 = generate_arma_data(intercept, [], ma_coefs, std_eps, n_periods) 

# Fit the model
model = SARIMAX(data_ma_2, order=(0, 0, 2), seasonal_order=(0, 0, 0, 0), trend='c')
results_ma = model.fit()

# Display results
print(results_ma.summary()) # Yields terrible parameter estimates (c, ma.L1, ma.L2) = (0.002, 0.261, -0.069)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments I have cleaned up the code and made my confusion explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into a similar issue: it seems to be the case that the variance of the errors is too low $(\sigma_{\epsilon}^2 = (0.001)^2)$ to properly estimate coefficients for the MA terms. Could be a number precision thing I'm not sure about that. Either way, increasing the variance of the errors fixes my issue.